# How do I stack just two of my three fields?

Tags: charts, powerbi

I have 3 different fields from 3 different queries.  I want to stack the 2 fields, Amount(Enq) and Amount(Var), and have the Budget Amt Enquiries beside the 2 stacked fields.

This is what my chart looks right now:

[image]

How do I get the 2 amount columns stacked with the budget next to it?  I am currently using a Cluster column chart, which I know isn't correct. When I use a stacked chart, it puts the Amount columns in with the Budget. I need the budget beside the two Amount columns that I want stacked. Any help is greatly appreciated.  Below is my desired result.

[image]

Kindest, Zorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an *ideal* setup for a `Line and stacked column chart`, and I really think it would be less confusing than having some columns that are stacked and some that are not.

The following data should match the structure as yours:

```
Area,Enq,Var,Budget
CEEA,2,2,3
CEEA,1,1,3
CEEA,2,3,4
UK,6,4,12
UK,5,4,6
UK,7,6,13
WE,6,3,8
WE,9,7,10
WE,4,1,4
USA,6,5,14
USA,4,5,11
USA,4,3,2
```

If you set it up in a table like this:

[image]

Then you can set up a `Line and stacked column chart` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best you could do here would be to create a custom measure that sums the Amount(ENQ) + Amount(VAR) and call it [Amount(ENQ) + Amount(VAR)].  You would lose insight to the relative ENQ vs VAR, but you would see them consolidated.  Charts are either all the way stacked or all the way clustered, to my knowledge.